# Get process list from kernel space in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

How can I get list of all pairs `process_name -> process_pid` (user space and kernel space) from kernel module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your kernel module, you can do something like this:

```
    rcu_read_lock();
    for_each_process(g) {
            printk("%s --> %d\n", g->comm, task_tgid_vnr(g));
    }
    rcu_read_unlock();
```